# Material2 - Two dynamic md-table on the same page, don't work

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Why if I add two component on the same page those component do not "do" the same? but only this at first in top

like this:

```
<h1>Angualr + Material</h1>
<button md-raised-button (click)="addEvent()">Add row for all ... to array</button>
<br><br>
<table-cart [tableData]="tableData"></table-cart>
<br><br>
<span>The same page but other place for example in other tab</span>
<br><br>
<table-cart [tableData]="tableData"></table-cart>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/YFL0wdGGXrwtjs4Exrx1?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are using `ViewChild`. It gets the first instance of the specified element. You need to use `ViewChildren` instead and iterate over all and update.

> In your plunker code, change `@ViewChild` line to this:

```
@ViewChildren(TableCartComponent) tableCarts: QueryList<TableCartComponent>
```

> ... and your `addEvent` method will become this:

```
    addEvent() {
        this.tableData.push({
            lp: this.tableData.length + 1,
            name: "name like...",
            code: "1111",
            color: "blue",
            size: "S",
            price: "99.99"
        });
        this.tableCarts.forEach(tableCart => tableCart.update());
        //this.TableCart.update();
    }
```

---

Here is a link to the updated [**PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/rK0Puu04HJjmIS9d8f2d?p=preview)